# Is it possible to save wordpress time to a jquery/javsacript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, date, time

I am trying this snippet but it prints invalid date to the console

```
var tim = new Date("<?php echo date(get_option('date_format')); ?>");
```

Comment: What does that line of php look like once it's been rendered to javascript, any obvious errors there?  Check the browser view source or your browser developer tools.

Comment: No. When I printed the variable value to console it printed "invalid date". no other errors. The output line highlighted.

`console.log(tim);`

Comment: So, when php has done its work this line of code will be rendered to something like `var tim = new Date("June 17th")`, what I was asking is whether that part succeeded or you ended up with something more like `var tim = new Date("Fatal PHP error")`

Comment: No. No errors like you are asking